# Does `yield from` have O(1) time complexity?

Tags: python, yield-from

Consider the following code snippet.

```py
from typing import Iterable


def geometric_progression(
    start: float, multiplier: float, num_elements: int
) -> Iterable[float]:
    assert num_elements >= 0
    if num_elements > 0:
        yield start
        yield from geometric_progression(
            start * multiplier, multiplier, num_elements - 1
        )
```

This function returns the first `num_elements` of the geometric progression starting with `start` and multipliying by `multiplier` each time. It's easy to see that the last element will be passed through one yield-statement and `num_elements-1` yield-from-statements. Does this function have `O(num_elements)` time complexity, or does it have `O(num_elements**2)` time complexity due to a "ladder" of nested yield-from-statements of depths 0, 1, 2, ..., `num_elements-2`, `num_elements-1`?

---

EDIT: I've come up with a simpler code snippet to demonstrate what I am asking.

```py
from typing import Iterable, Any

def identity_with_nested_yield_from(depth: int, iterable: Iterable[Any]) -> Iterable[Any]:
    assert depth >= 1
    if depth == 1:
        yield from iterable
    else:
        yield from identity_with_nested_yield_from(depth-1, iterable)
```

Is this function `O(depth + length of iterable)`, or is it `O(depth * length of iterable)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could've sworn there was an optimization in place to shortcut these kinds of `yield from` chains, but testing shows no such optimization, and I couldn't find anything in the places I thought the optimization was implemented either.

The generators on each level of a `yield from` chain must be suspended and resumed individually to pass `yield` and `send` values up and down the chain. Your function has `O(num_elements**2)` time complexity. Also, it hits a stack overflow once the call stack reaches a depth of 1000.

Answer (score 1):

`yield from` is [formally equivalent](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/#formal-semantics) to a *loop* of `response = yield child.send(response)`, plus error propagation and handling. When consumed in iteration, the `response` is always `None` and no errors are propagated/handled. This is equivalent to a `for` loop.

```
# `yield from child` without error handling/response
for x in child:
    yield x
```

Thus, each `yield from` has the time/space complexity of iterating its argument. Stacking `yield from` of a size `n` child a total of `m` times thus has a time complexity of `O(nm)`.