# Do we create n iterators when we use yield recursively?

Tags: python

Consider:

```
def iterInOrder(node):
    if node.left:
        for n in iterInOrder(node.left):
            yield n
    yield node
    if node.right:
        for n in iterInOrder(node.right):
            yield n
```

And let `n` be number of nodes in the input binary tree, Do we create a single generator that yields n nodes? Or do we create `n` iterators that each generate a node? what can you say about space/time complexity of that code comparing to a simple recursive travel:

```
def visitInOrder(node):
    if node.left:
        visitInOrder(node.left)
    visit(node)
    if node.right:
        visitInOrder(node.right)
```

I care more for Python 2, but may be nice to know if answer differs for Python 3.

Comment: You create `n` generators, each of which yields anywhere between 1 node (for the leaf nodes) and `n` nodes (for the root node). If you weren't stuck with Python 2.x, you could make the code a bit more concise by using `yield from` instead of explicitly iterating over the sub-generators, but I don't think that changes the complexity at all.

Comment: similar or duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61591596/does-yield-from-have-o1-time-complexity

Answer (score 3):

In CPython, each call to `iterInOrder()` creates a new generator-iterator, regardless of Python version, and regardless of whether it's a top-level or recursive call.

Similarly, each call to `visitInOrder()` creates a new stack frame, again regardless of Python version or context.

So the space complexity is `O(depth(tree))` either way (which doesn't have a useful relation, in general, to the number of nodes - the tree may be `n` levels deeps, or 2 levels deep).

Time is a different calculation, but subtle because it's barely ever noticeable:  the recursive version has `O(n)` time complexity, but that's a lower bound on the generator version.  Each time you `yield`, the yielded value is passed up the chain of recursive generator calls, one level at a time, until it's finally consumed by the top-level call.  Then, when the chain is resumed, the stack of generator-iterator frames is reactivated one at a time, until getting back down to the original `yield`.

So in the generator version there is a time component quadratic in `depth(tree)`.  But unless the tree is very deep, you'll probably never notice that, because in CPython all that stack unwinding and rewinding occurs "at C speed".

Comment: For a binary tree (which the code implies is being used here), the smallest possible maximum depth is `ceil(log2(n))`. But otherwise this is a fantastic analysis!

Comment: Ah, thanks @Blckknght - I indeed overlooked the "binary" part.